# uiimageview within a uiview also within a button shows uiimage blurred

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

So I have a button with a custom uiview that contain a uiimageview.

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 29, 29);

UIView  *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 29, 29)];


UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sexy-pic-of-me"];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,29,29);

[myView addSubview:myImageView];
[myButton addSubview:myView];

[self.view addSubview: myButton];
```

My image is blurry no matter how much in increase or decrease the size. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably because your image dimensions aren't a 1:1 ratio, and because it's to large or small.

Comment: What are the original dimensions of your image?

Comment: image dimension is 29X29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other folks have mentioned two of the possible causes of fuzziness

- the image size doesn't match the frame size, resulting in scaling
- the image aspect ratio is being adjusted due to the content mode

The third possible cause is the use of odd numbers in the frame.  From my experience, if the center.x and/or center.y of a UIView is not a whole number, then fuzziness results.  For example, if you set the frame as

```
someView.frame = CGRect( 100, 100, 29, 29 );
```

then things get fuzzy because the center point of said view will be `CGPoint( 114.5, 114.5 )`.  This problem is mainly seen on the non-retina devices.  Retina devices have two pixels per point, so half-a-point coordinates are ok, but other off-grid coordinates could still cause fuzziness.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a content mode i.e.:

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Read more about content modes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode

```
UIViewContentMode
Options to specify how a view adjusts its content when its size changes.

typedef enum {
   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
   UIViewContentModeRedraw,
   UIViewContentModeCenter,
   UIViewContentModeTop,
   UIViewContentModeBottom,
   UIViewContentModeLeft,
   UIViewContentModeRight,
   UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
   UIViewContentModeTopRight,
   UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
   UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```